# Standalone flash player that can start full screen

Tags: windows-7, command-line, flash

Adobe forgot to add a command line parameter to start their standalone Flash player in full screen mode. Oops!

Is there an alternative standalone player for Windows 7 that can take an SWF file name as a command line parameter and can be started full screen, and can hide the mouse cursor?

It does not have to be free but should cost less than $30.